# Representing the empty set on an Euler diagram

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I try to describe with Euler diagram the following relations: $A \oplus A = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subset (A \cap B) \subset (A \cup B)$. But empty set confuses me.

I even cannot imagine how to use Euler diagram with the first expression. But the second one I understand partially (I hope so):

[image]

How in fact to show $\emptyset$ in Euler diagram like in expressions above?

Comment: What does $A \oplus A$ mean? Also, in the notation you're using, if $X \subset Y$, can $X = Y$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, $\oplus$ is symmetric difference

Comment: Then $A\oplus A = \emptyset$ for every set $A$.

Comment: Yes, but in this case how one should show $\emptyset$ in Euler diagram?

Comment: Could you answer the second question from my first comment? That will help me to help you.

Comment: There's no precise definition to it. But I think that one can consider X = Y in X $\subset$ Y. It is like X $\subset$ U, I think - X can be a part of Universal set or Universal set itself by content.

Comment: It is the same. I was asking about the symbol $\subset$. Some people write $X \subset Y$ to mean that $X$ is a subset of $Y$ but not equal to $Y$, whereas others allow the possibility that $X = Y$. It seems that you use the notation to allow equality between the two sets.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11149/discussion-between-michael-albanese-and-dragon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $A\oplus A = \emptyset$, where $\oplus$ is symmetric difference, is satisfied by every set $A$ as $$A\oplus A = (A\setminus A)\cup(A\setminus A) = \emptyset\cup\emptyset = \emptyset.$$ Therefore, if you want to draw an Euler diagram to represent this condition, just draw any set $A$.

The condition $\emptyset \subset A\cap B \subset A\cup B$, where $\subset$ allows for the possibility of equality, is satisfied by any two sets $A$ and $B$. Clearly $\emptyset \subset A\cap B$ as $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set, and any element which is in both $A$ and $B$ is in at least one of them so $A\cap B \subset A\cup B$. Therefore, to draw a Euler diagram to represent this condition, just draw any two sets $A$ and $B$.